# How to get original request URI in EL spring-boot page behind httpd proxypass

Tags: apache, spring-boot, el, proxypass, embedded-tomcat-7

I have a spring-boot web application with embedded tomcat, running on port 28081, and httpd configured for proxying like this:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:28081/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:28081/
```

Then in a jsp page I need to pass the full request URL to a silverlight widget;but

```
${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}
```

will resolve to `http://localhost:28081`.

So I thought to rely on `X-Forwarded-Host`, but there are cases when it does contain more than one proxy address, separated by comma. I am not sure it is safe to trust the order of the addresses will be preserved.

Is there a better way to do this, be that in the jsp, in the httpd configuration or in the controller code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the controller you can use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder`: initialize it from the request and it picks out the proxy headers and builds the URI for the origin for you, e.g. `String uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().build().toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ProxyPreserveHost`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) in your httpd config to keep the original `Host` header, i.e. your outward domain name, but I can't think of a good way to pass the port.

Comment: And `proxy_set_header Host $host;` for nginx.